# How to convert HTTP Response to JSON in Blazor

Tags: c#, json, http, blazor

I am trying to convert an HTTP response with the following format:

```
[
  {
    ID: 1
    ...
  },
  {
    ID: 2
    ...
  }
]
```

Into JSON so it looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      ID: 1
      ...
    },
    {
      ID: 2
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone know how I can do this in C# (so that it can be deserialized by a Blazor application)?

There isn't any way to add an argument to the HTTP request to coerce the response into JSON format, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
json="{\n data:"+json+"\n}";
```

output

```
{
 data:[
  {
    "ID": 1
  },
  {
    "ID": 2
  }
]
}
```